# Toggle method for modal isn't working through javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

What should have been a very simple thing to do is making itself it very tough. Simple method to toggle modal isn't working from javascript. Here is the code:

```
<div class="modal1 mfp-hide" id="modal-signup">
<div class="block divcenter" style="background-color: #FFF; max-width: 400px;">
    <div style="padding: 50px;">
        <h3 class="font-body">Signup for an account</h3>
        <div class="help-block with-errors has-errors" id ="signupError"></div>
        <form action="#" id="signup_modal" method="post" class="nobottommargin">
            <div class="form-process"></div>
            <div class="col_full">
                <label class="font-body capitalize" for="signup-form-modal-name">Name:</label>
                <input type="text" id="signup_form_modal_name" name="signup-form-modal-name" value="" class="form-control" required />
            </div>
            <div class="col_full">
                <label class="font-body capitalize" for="signup-form-modal-username">Email:</label>
                <input type="text" id="signup_form_modal_username" name="signup-form-modal-username" value="" class="form-control" required />
            </div>
            <div class="col_full">
                <label class="font-body capitalize" for="signup-form-modal-password">Password:</label>
                <input type="password" id="signup_form_modal_password" name="signup-form-modal-password" value="" class="form-control" required />
            </div>
            <div class="col_full">
                <label class="font-body capitalize" for="signup-form-modal-password">Repeat Password:</label>
                <input type="password" id="signup_form_modal_repassword" name="signup-form-modal-repassword" value="" class="form-control" required />
            </div>
            <div class="col_full">
                <label class="font-body capitalize" for="signup-form-modal-mobile">Mobile:</label>
                <input type="text" id="signup_form_modal_mobile" name="signup-form-modal-mobile" value="" class="form-control" required />
            </div>
            <div class="col_full nobottommargin">
                <button class="button button-rounded nomargin" id="signup_form_modal_submit" name="signup-form-modal-submit" value="signup">Signup</button>
            </div>
        </form>
        <div class="line line-sm"></div>
        <a href="#" class="button button-rounded btn-block t400 center capitalize si-facebook si-colored noleftmargin norightmargin">Signup with Facebook</a>
        <a href="#" class="button button-rounded btn-block t400 center capitalize si-gplus si-colored nomargin">Signup with Google</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
$("#signup_form_modal_submit").click(function(e){
        $.post("<?php echo BASE_URL.'/login/register';?>",  $('#signup_modal').serialize(),function(data){
                if(data['a']==1){
                    $("#modal-signup").modal('toggle');
                    //$("#modal-signup").modal('hide');
                    //$("[data-dismiss=modal]").trigger({ type: "click" });
                }
        }
});
```

There is no issue with any js as everything else works fine. Even clicking on close button of this modal closes this fine, seems the issue is with js only.

I want to close this modal and open another one. Can anybody help in this?

Comment: Check what do you get in response, go `console.log(data)` before the IF statement, or check in browser inspector, Network tab.

Comment: It's something that I'm sending from ajax response. It's an array.

Comment: is response json ??

Comment: Yes response is json.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$("#signup_form_modal_submit").click(function(e){
        $.post("<?php echo BASE_URL.'/login/register';?>",  $('#signup_modal').serialize(),function(data){
               var jsondata = $.parseJSON(data);
                if(jsondata.a ==1 ){
                    $("#modal-signup").modal('toggle');
                    //$("#modal-signup").modal('hide');
                    //$("[data-dismiss=modal]").trigger({ type: "click" });
                }
        }
});
```

Comment: It throws an error, "SyntaxError: JSON Parse error: Unexpected identifier "object"

Comment: `console.log(data);` before parsing it what do u get ?

Comment: {a: 1, otp: "521599"}

Comment: i think its already a json object 
remove `var jsondata = $.parseJSON(data);` n
`jsondata.a` to `data.a`

Comment: Nope, now no error, but it's not working. Strange thing is it even darkens the background keeping the modal as it is.

Comment: And then if I click on close button manually, it closes modal but makes a background non-performing with darker shades.

Comment: which model ur using ?

Comment: As in? I'm using default bootstrap provider modal.

Comment: bootstrap 3 or 4 ?
can u post more of your model html ?